# Protractor-cucumber database

Tags: javascript, database, protractor, automated-tests

I have a protractor-cucumber framework for my e2e automated tests. As you know when we test UI we sometimes like to compare it with database values. Or sometimes we perform the certain functions in UI and would like to test the persistence of data in the DB. In my case it is a oracle DB.

Could someone suggest 
- if it is good idea to cover such tests using protractor
- if yes, then how can I go about implementing these steps. A high level idea/steps or probably a sample should be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The challenge in your case is to accomplish querying Oracle DB.  Oracle supply a nodejs package [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) for Nodejs to use Oracle DB, But installing this package is not easy as installing Java Oracle DB Driver, and its precondition before install is not across platform.

Comment: I think you are referring to this : https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md    am I right ? Your reply made me wonder, if other automation testers are not testing the DB for a angular app? e2e tests involve backend as well-  then why are folks not using this more often. I see very few resources for this topic

Comment: your given url is right,  you can practice to install it to feel it's easy or hard for you

Comment: I took the sample file from the node  oracle gitbub project, placed it in my protractor-cucumber  project and did the other install steps to run it. I can run a simple SELECT Statement. Now, the challenge is using the similar set up in my step definition. I am not sure how to structure the code because it is all async and the query doesn't even get executed in the step definition , the test case is marked complete

Comment: Read the example code from here : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md,   For async, you need to invoke the `callback()` function when the step is done, or return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to test accessing the DB directly or you can just use API calls to get the data from the database ? I find a bit risky to manipulate the database directly. If you have a choice, I would say to use sync-request to get the value that the server gets from the database.

Comment: The test case needs to be set up in such a way that , the test data is inserted, test case verification is done and the test data is deleted. In other words, set up(), execute() and tear down(). I am surprised why there are no resources or examples for such tests when it comes to protractor. Such tests are quite common in testing world.

Comment: "If you have a choice, I would say to use sync-request to get the value that the server gets from the database" -- what is a sync-request